# String as char[] array in C# 3.0?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

The [C# 3.0 spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx) has the following code example in section 10.6.1.3 "Output parameters":

```
using System;
class Test
{
    static void SplitPath(string path, out string dir, out string name) {
        int i = path.Length;
        while (i > 0) {
            char ch = path[i – 1];
            if (ch == '\\' || ch == '/' || ch == ':') break;
            i--;
        }
        dir = path.Substring(0, i);
        name = path.Substring(i);
    }
    static void Main() {
        string dir, name;
        SplitPath("c:\\Windows\\System\\hello.txt", out dir, out name);
        Console.WriteLine(dir);
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

I cannot get this code to compile in VS2005/C#2.0. Did the behavior of strings in C# 3.0 change so that a string can be referred as a char[] array without explicitly converting it (the statement "ch = path[i - 1]")?

Comment: Jim - notice how your replies below got out of sync with the answer you were replying to?  You'll want to add your replies as comments, rather than adding a new answer, to ensure that the conversation flows.

You don't have the reputation to make comments yet, I see, but so you know...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an invalid character '–'. Change '–' to '-'

Comment: Thanks darin! Didn't notice that, was completely looking at the wrong thing!

Comment: The language spec is written in MSWord, which converts minus signs to en-dashes.  It looks better on print outs, but messes up compiles.

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting?

System.String has had [] accessors since .NET v1.0

Answer (score 0):

According MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(VS.71).aspx ) this was even possible in .net 1.1 you can of course have a

string myString = "Filip Ekberg";

And then access the first char by doing myString[0]

Answer (score 0):

The dash character you see in your code block is an em-dash not a minus symbol.  They look similar but they're different.  Wherever you cut and pasted the code from has changed it to an incorrect character.

```
char ch = path[i - 1];
```

is perfectly valid (so long as the - is a minus and not a dash)

Answer (score 0):

On a sidenote, why would you split a path and a filename like that? There's a lot of very useful functions to do that for you in the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx) class.

Use Path.GetFileName() for the filename, Path.GetDirectoryName() for the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, but the code you pasted in your question has an 'm-dash' character (hex 96) instead of a minus sign (hex 2D) -- maybe it's a font issue?